# how to get color from a line plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to plot several normal distributions, and add labels to each one in its line color. However the color does not seem to update.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats

def single_plot(mu, sigma, ax, label=None):
    x = np.linspace(mu - 4*sigma, mu + 4*sigma, 1000)
    ax = sns.lineplot(x, stats.norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma), ax=ax, label=label, zorder=2)

    #my code to get color
    color = ax.get_lines()[0].get_c() #fetch color of line
    ax.text(mu, max(stats.norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma)), label, fontsize=16, color=color)
```

When put to use, however, this does not update the color with each line. If I try:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = single_plot(mu=1000, sigma=100, ax=ax, label='test1')
ax = single_plot(mu=1500, sigma=200, ax=ax, label='test2')
fig.show()
```

I am getting this figure. The label for "test2" was not updated.

[image]

I am wondering where I was wrong and how to fix this problem.

Comment: You might try `ax.get_lines()[-1].get_c()` to pick the last line's color.

Comment: Besides what @ImportanceOfBeingErnest mentions, why do you use `color[:3]`?

Comment: @b-fg Oops. That is something that is not appropriate for this example data. I was giving different alpha values for each plot to make the most important curve stand out. However, if I use RGBA, the text appears so light for curves with small alpha that it was almost unreadable. Thus I used colors[:3] to only get the RGB. I have fixed it in the original question.

Comment: so did the @ImportanceOfBeingErnest comment work?

Comment: @b-fg it worked out great.